# Ignore screen reader text in serenity

Tags: selenium, testing, automated-tests, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

serenity is returning the screen reader text along with the visible text in the screen. How to get text which is visible to the user?

```
public static Target TransactionTypeOption = Target.the("Transaction Type options").located(By.xpath("//ipb-dropdown[@class='type-dropdown ']//li//div"));      
List<String> options = Text.of(TransactionTypeOption).viewedBy(actor).asList();
```

[image]

I have used bootstrap Sr-only class for the screen reader text.
So, I just wanted to read the first content which is "All Transactions" but serenity is returning me "All Transactions white spaces , current selection"

Answer (score 0):

The XPath you are using is selecting the `div`, which also picks up some text under the `div`, which is `, current selection` in this case. I've seen this issue before with Selenium, and the only solution is to handle the extra text in your code.

```
public static Target TransactionTypeOption = Target.the("Transaction Type options").located(By.xpath("//ipb-dropdown[@class='type-dropdown ']//li//div"));

string textToFilterOut = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='sr-only']")).getText();      
List<String> options = Text.of(TransactionTypeOption).replace(textToFilterOut, "").viewedBy(actor).asList();
```

Comment: Every individual div in the list has the sr-only element. how to handle that?

Comment: @ChandreshMishra Does `.located(By.xpath("//ipb-dropdown[@class='type-dropdown ']//li//div"));` find one `div` element or multiple `div` elements?

Comment: it finds multiple. It is a dropdown value.